# Consecutive values bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery, partition

I got the "type" and "previous row" fileds and trying to produce "consecutive values" filed

I tried to use `count () over (partition by type , previouse row )`
but the value does not reset after "previous row" change

| type | previous row | Consecutive values |
| --- | --- | --- |
| X | 1 | 2 |
| X | 1 | 1 |
| X | 0 | 3 |
| X | 0 | 2 |
| X | 0 | 1 |
| X | 1 | 2 |
| X | 1 | 1 |

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to achieve your goal - you need to have some indication of how rows to be ordered. Usually some sort of date or timestamp or any other means that allows to order on. so let's assume you have an extra column available called ts that define that order - like in example below

[image]

so in this case consider below solution

```
select * except(change, grp),
  count(1) over(partition by type, grp order by ts desc) Consecutive_values
from (
  select *, countif(change) over(partition by type order by ts) grp
  from (
    select *, 
      ifnull(value != lag(value) over(partition by type order by ts), true) change
    from data
  )
)
# order by ts
```

if apply to sample data  - output is

[image]